# A way to reload the ViewDidLoad on each run swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, viewdidload

I'm making this small game with swift and the game is set up using the viewDidLoad. Each day the game is suppose to be slightly different, but that depends on that the viewDidLoad runs. So let's say a user plays at day 1 and keeps the game active to day 2, the game won't function on day 2 since the viewDidLoad wasn't run.
For the game to function properly I need to run the VieDidLoad each time "applicationDidBecomeActive", to make sure it runs as it should.

I've tried to do like this:

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) 
{
myViewController?.viewDidLoad()
}
```

I also tried to wrap my code that is inside viewDidLoad like this and run it in applicationDidBecomeActive. But that doesn't do it.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
   func refreshView()
   {
    //all the code goes here
    }
}
```

Any idea what I could do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your view controller to listen `applicationDidBecomeActive` notifications and run the configuration method when it receives it

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "refreshView:",
    name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
    object: nil)
```

Comment: Will try this. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I hope that's what you need. Don't forget to accept my answer as solution if it works.

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad` method not meant to load many times, this will be called only once per lifecycle of `viewController` when view first created an loads into memory, and this is not right approach call this again and again.

What you want is possible without loading `viewDidLoad` again and again, move your `refreshView` method out of `viewDidLoad` and call it when required, you can call it once form `viewDidLoad` and after that you can call it again when required.

You can respond to application `notification` methods like 
`UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` or in 
`UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and then figure out do you want to refresh view or not, if you want to refresh view just call your `refresView` method.

Your code should look like this

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
   super.viewDidLoad()
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "OnAppBecameActive", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)

   refreshView()
}

func refreshView()
{
    //all the code goes here
}
```

And add this method as well

```
func OnAppBecameActive()
{
// Add logic here to check if need to call refresh view method
if needToRefreshView
{
  refreshView()
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same probelm but i solve it with call

```
self.viewDidLoad()
```

On my Func I wanna to call my view did load again from it.